# Press button with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Exist a lot of such questions, but nothing helps? 
I try to click "save" button, before I have successful sent values with Selenium to table. 
I try this code:

```
river.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='field_0_9']")).click();
```

I have no exceptions here, just this code line do nothing.
Also I try by CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='sybmit'][value='Save']")).click();
```

same problem.
[image]

Comment: What code do you get when you record a macro and try clicking the button?

Comment: I have no exceptions, no errors, if you mean this. Just code doesn't do expected work

Comment: I'm saying - try recording a macro, then click on the button, and see what code is generated by the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the save button is nested in a frame. Try this:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='frame_content']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='do_save_data']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot I can see a `<frame>` element, so I assume this input is inside the frame. You need to switch into the frame before clicking.

Without seeing your `<frame>` element's actual HTML, I can only give the following suggestion:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // make sure you are out of all frames
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame")));

// continue do your stuff
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='sybmit'][value='Save']")).click();
```

If the situation is you are already inside the frame, but you need to jump out. (I can't determine which situation you are facing due to lack of context.)

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

// continue do your stuff
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='sybmit'][value='Save']")).click();
```